# display records from mongodb meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to display the records from a mongodb collection to my meteorjs app

template

```
<head>
  <title>simple</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>
    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{title}}</li>
</template>
```

main.js

```
tasks_list = new Mongo.Collection('todoList');
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.body.helpers({
     tasks: function(){
        return tasks_list.find();
     }
    });

}

if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.startup(function(){
        // code to run on server at start up
    });
}
```

and I'm sure I have 'todoList' collection as I check it by 'db.todoList.find()' but sadly there are no records displaying from 'todoList' collection when I tried to render it unto my meteor app, any ideas, help please?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems ok. Make sure you either have the auto-publish packaged installed, or you manage the publish/subscribe correctly, so that when you run tasks_list.find() on the client, it actually finds the documents.

As a quick test, open the browser console, and type tasks_list.find().fecth() to see if the expected documents are returned.

Comment: yes the expected document was return, any ideas why the records not displaying in my meteorjsApp?

Comment: A very basic question: do your documents in the collection really have a property named "title". If you can, please post here the results you get when you run the fetch command in the browser console.